# Find the city with the highest temperature in the last 50 years

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm learning Mapreduce concept. And came across with one learning case study which I want to understand.

Lets say I have data of 5 cities(A, B, C, D, E) temperatures of last 50 years, then how map reduce will work in this query ? They way I'm thinking it requires more than one level of reducers group to get final result. ( Is it correct in Hadoop map reduce framework ?)

Steps:

All 50 cities data of last 50 years (HDFS)

Splits into three chunks (Mapper 1, Mapper 2, Mapper 3, these are different nodes in cluster,  Am I correct ?)

Shuffle sort (At this position I have one question as well, Is it the place where code executes on data chunks ?) Where it got to know cities with their max temperatures out of that specific chunk of data.

Reducer - Where cities with max temperatures from diff sort and shuffles will come out to reducers.

So My question is, The same reducer will also figure out the City with max temperature or one more reducer will come into picture to pick up the city with Max temperature ?

Second My question is, At which point( Mapper or Sort Shuffle or Else ) code starts working on data ?

Answer (score 1):

Have the Mapper output all city data by the last 50 years. If you are using Pig or Spark, you'd use a `filter` command. HIVE would be a `WHERE` clause. Otherwise, it's a simple `if-else` in code.

In theory, you can have one reducer collecting all the cities with all the temperatures of the last 50 years, then scan them all, however that defeats the parallelism of MapReduce. There's nothing wrong with multiple map/reduce stages. In fact, Pig, Hive, Cascading, and all the other higher level MR tools will do just that.

So, the (first) Reducer will be handed a collection of temperatures for any given city. All it needs to do is find the maximum, then outputs the (city, max) tuple. Each reducer will output one tuple per line for each city.

A (second) Mapper can use the same InputFormat as before, but this time, the Reducer can be used to collect all the cities as previously avoided. This time is more efficient because there is less data shuffled around. Then, the absolute max can be found.

In Hive, you simply append `ORDER BY temp DESC LIMIT 1` and you have your answer.

> Splits into three chunks (Mapper 1, Mapper 2, Mapper 3, these are different nodes in cluster, Am I correct ?)

Map tasks can run on the same nodes, and ideally run wherever the HDFS blocks for the data exist. The amount of mappers is controlled by the block size, the InputSplits, and therefore the size of the input file(s).

Code is running on data at every stage. [The output of the mapper will optionally be sent to a Combiner, a Partitioner, then shuffled and sorted to a Reducer](https://farm3.static.flickr.com/2275/3529146683_c8247ff6db_o.png)

Comment: cricket_007, Lets say if Map1 result is having two cities(for ex a, b) of max same temperature  and Map2 is having output of two cities(for ex b, c) of max same temperature and Map3 only one lets say c.So In output there would be 4 reducers one for a type city a, second for b and so on ?Reducer   holding two values of cities(in case of city b) from two mappers(map1 and map2) can have same temperature or different as well. So how it works further, I mean any operation are available like you said where, if or distinct etc to solve this condition ? Is reducer itself is an output file or it send ?

Comment: I really don't understand what you just said, but having same values isn't a problem for the reducer, regardless of how many there are

Comment: Okay..I mean to ask is different reducers are having different set of data's output from HDFS. So How does it work, adding all results from multiple reducers to a single output  then calculating a single result out of that ?

Comment: The first reducer outputs to an intermediate folder, from which the second mapper reads from, yes.